# cant disable Sager np9390 Keyboard Backlight

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-backlight

I want to disable my Sager keyboard backlight in /sys/class/leds I only  have scrolllock numlock and capslock.

It should be able to change colours and brightness but it's stuck at the default blue I just want it off.

Sager np9390 also known as Clevo PS375sm.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with a Clevo N850HJ (although it was defaulting to green). There's no module in the linux kernel by default to deal with Clevo keyboard backlights, as I understand it.

I tried "[clevo-xsm-wmi](https://bitbucket.org/tuxedocomputers/clevo-xsm-wmi/overview)", and it worked. Don't know if it will work for the PS375sm, as the nearest mentioned on the link I provided is PS370SM-A, but it's worth a try.

(Note: this doesn't expose the leds in /sys/class/leds, but it does make the function key combinations work, and you can set options for the module it provides that set the initial state, so it can be coded to force the backlight off on boot)